# How to recreate PIL palette image using OpenCV? (confusion with P mode)

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I am trying to replace part of the code originally written with PIL by OpenCV.
Ideally, I would like to eliminate PIL or at least make that input (first_frame) is OpenCV array.

Original (PIL) code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

first_frame_path = "00000.png"
image2 = Image.open(first_frame_path)
print(image2.mode) # out: P <---

image2_p = image2.convert("P")
image2_pil = np.array(image2_p)
print(image2_pil.mean()) # out: 0.039107 <---
```

OpenCV code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import cv2

first_frame_path = "00000.png"

image = cv2.imread(first_frame_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)

image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
image_from_array = Image.fromarray(image)
print(image_from_array.mode) # out: RGB <---

image_p = image_from_array.convert("P")
image_pil = np.array(image_p)
print(image_pil.mean()) # out: 0.48973 <---
```

**How should I adapt my OpenCV code to make that *image_pil* has the same values as *image2_pil*?**

I computed the ***mean()*** only to present that these two arrays are different, and my goal is to obtain same results.

I am working with simple mask:
[image]

I understand that the difference comes from the fact that in original code mask is directly loaded as P, contradicting to OpenCV code, where it is RGB. Unfortunately, I don't have an idea how to fix it. I tried to specify:

```
Image.fromarray(image, mode="P")
```

However, then I am getting error:

> Exception has occurred: ValueError Too many dimensions: 3 > 2.

Could you please tell me what can I do to obtain the same NumPy array as in original code?

Comment: In P mode your pixels will be palette indexes, and averaging those indexes will be meaningless.

Comment: What you haven't said here is what you want the pixels to be.  Do you want a single 8-bit grayscale value for each pixel?

Comment: The mean of P mode (color palette) is meaningless to the actual colors. It is just the mean of the 256 entry table (represented as a grayscale image whose values point to different 256 or less colors) that points to the closest colors to those of the RGB values.  Why are you computing the mean of the P mode image?  What do you want to learn from that?  I do not think OpenCV supports pseudocode palette form for color images.  Any P mode PNG will be read in and converted to BGR channels.

Comment: Does this help? `image_from_array.convert("first_frame_path")` instead of `image_from_array.convert("P")`

Comment: Averaging the palette indices is meaningless. Say black was entry 0 in your image, with red as 1 and green as 2. Your mean palette index will be close to 0. Now, what if PIL chooses a palette where black is entry 255, red is 254 and green is 253. The mean of your palette indices will now be near 255, but the image will look the same.

Comment: @toyotaSupra that does not help. `Image.convert()` (`image_from_array` is an `Image`) does not understand paths. `Image.fromarray()` doesn't either. why would you suggest anything that is plainly nonsensical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does what you want. It relies on allowing PIL to convert the image to RGB and thence back to palette-mode creating (or recreating) the palette in its own (hopefully deterministic) way each time.

In general, what you are doing is really rather ill-advised...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Load original image
im = Image.open('26dQH.png')

# Convert to RGB, then back to palette so that **PIL decides the palette**
im = im.convert('RGB').convert('P', palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE)

# Get its colours
print(f'im.getcolors(): {im.getcolors()}')
# prints im.getcolors(): [(5367, 0), (5297, 1), (399256, 2)]

# Print first 3 palette entries
print(np.array(im.getpalette()).reshape((-1,3))[:3])

# Prints:
# [[  0 128   0]
#  [128   0   0]
#  [  0   0   0]]

# Read same image using OpenCV and convert to palette-mode PIL Image
na = cv.imread('26dQH.png', cv.IMREAD_COLOR)
pi = Image.fromarray(na).convert('P', palette=Image.Palette.ADAPTIVE)

# Get its colours
print(f'pi.getcolors(): {pi.getcolors()}') 
# prints pi.getcolors(): [(5367, 0), (5297, 1), (399256, 2)]

# Print first 3 palette entries
print(np.array(im.getpalette()).reshape((-1,3))[:3])
# Prints:
# [[  0 128   0]
#  [128   0   0]
#  [  0   0   0]]
```

---

Note that you can check the palette of a PNG with `pngcheck` like this:

```
pngcheck -p  26dQH.png
zlib warning:  different version (expected 1.2.11, using 1.2.12)

File: 26dQH.png (2063 bytes)
  PLTE chunk: 256 palette entries
      0:  (  0,  0,  0) = (0x00,0x00,0x00)
      1:  (128,  0,  0) = (0x80,0x00,0x00)
      2:  (  0,128,  0) = (0x00,0x80,0x00)
      3:  (128,128,  0) = (0x80,0x80,0x00)
      4:  (  0,  0,128) = (0x00,0x00,0x80)
      5:  (128,  0,128) = (0x80,0x00,0x80)
    ...
    ...
    ...
    253:  (224, 96,192) = (0xe0,0x60,0xc0)
    254:  ( 96,224,192) = (0x60,0xe0,0xc0)
    255:  (224,224,192) = (0xe0,0xe0,0xc0)
OK: 26dQH.png (854x480, 8-bit palette, non-interlaced, 99.5%).
```

---

Or you can use **ImageMagick** - which very usefully gets you the frequencies/counts of each palette entry (in the first column) too:

```
magick 26dQH.png -format %c histogram:info: 

    399256: (0,0,0) #000000 black
      5367: (0,128,0) #008000 green
      5297: (128,0,0) #800000 maroon
```

---

Or with `exiftool` like this:

```
exiftool -b -palette  26dQH.png | xxd -g 1 -c 3    
00000000: 00 00 00  ...   # entry 0
00000003: 80 00 00  ...   # entry 1
00000006: 00 80 00  ...   # entry 2
00000009: 80 80 00  ...
...
...
```